# Do we have any option to perform bulk update in elastic search without specifying the document id

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do bulk update via script in elastic search without specifying the document id. In 'Books' document type, I have author name. If I rename author name, I need to bulk update for all 'Books' which are having the updated author name by using script.

Do I need to get all the book ids having the author name and update all the books?

```
BulkResponse bulkResponse = client.prepareBulk().add(client.prepareUpdate().setIndex("test").setType("books").setScript(script)).execute().actionGet();
```

By using the above code I am getting the below exception

```
org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: id is missing;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mention is the update by query functionality. It's not available yet, but since there's a lot of demand for it I guess it will be available one day, you can have a loot at the related issue on github: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1607 .
The reason why it wasn't implemented yet is that it is potentially dangerous as it might lead to a lot of updates and potentially long running queries which cannot be stopped at this time.